# How to add a web link in tableview cell in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator

I want to add in my app a tableview where I can show my more app which are on app store with there icon and there name (behind the name link in hide) as user click on the link it will take him to app store.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you know how to present the table view, just open an URL of `itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/appname` once the user selects an app.

Comment: i have add apps name in the tableview using plist , but how to add icon with the each app name ???

Comment: It depends on how you want to present your table-view cells. The default cells (UITableViewCell) has a property imageView, so you can set this property to an UIImage object containing your icon. The style of UITableViewCell must be either UITableViewCellStyleDefault or UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.

Comment: be describe briefly .. ia m new to iphone

Comment: Describe yourself what you do not understand, or what problems you have so people can help you better. Do you know where a table-view cell is returned to your table view? Then set the cell's imageView property there to an UIImage object like cell.imageView = iconImage;

Comment: Your URL does not work for me, I replaced "appname" with my app's name, but nothing comes up when I call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/myappname"]]; can you give a full working example URL for an existing app?

Comment: OK I see that links like that work on the device but not the simulator, but just what is the "appname"?   There are many things that could be considered the app name.   Also in my case, my app name is in cyrillic, and the URL on the device to the app name on itunes doesn't work, is there anything to get a link to the app store for an app named with non-latin characters?    Update: I tried the "idxxxxxx" of the http itunes link and it didn't work, the only thing that worked was the apps full http:// link

Comment: @MHC have done almost all ..now i just want that whn user touch desried app it will take user to the app store at my apps link .. any hepl ?

Comment: NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
 
 //Create a URL object.
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
 
 //URL Requst Object
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 
} now wht to do to open that link in safari

Comment: It's in the above comment of Bogatyr. [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<URL>" ]]

Comment: !@mhc   http://itunes.apple.com/pk/app/mwatta-imam-malik/id331976269?mt=8&uo=4 ..when i put this link in my code it not open by my similatr safari but its workin well in my pc safari ??? wht to do now ///